# How to save a worksheet as a new workbook with pasted value to a specific folder with modified name?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still new to VBA.  I need to extract one worksheet with formulas to a new workbook as pasted value.  Save it to the another folder with the same name but adding "hc" at the end for hard copy. Also, the tab name should still stay the same from worksheet to workbook.  I found a formula that is similar to what I need but I don't know how to modify it so it would save to a specific folder or how to modify the name.  Can someone help me please?

Thank you

```
Sub ExporthisBOM()

    Dim fName

    Sheets("Radiant_Trades").Copy

    With ActiveSheet

        .UsedRange.Copy

        .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Save As")

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fName

End Sub
```

The above formula works.  Also, one to modify name but I don't understand how you can combine them or if there is an easier way to do everything I want.

```
Sub sbVBS_To_SaveAs_ActiveWorkbook()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:temptest1.xlsx"
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the source worksheet `Radiant_Trades` in the workbook containing this code? What are the source workbook's name (incl. extension) and its path? What is the destination path? What is the purpose of the line that ends with `xlPasteFormats`? Do you want to get rid of `GetSaveAsFilename` or does it suit your needs?

Comment: Is the source worksheet Radiant_Trades in the workbook containing this code? - yes. 
 What are the source workbook's name (incl. extension) and its path? test.xlsm  should work on any path since saved to different folders with different months.  What is the destination path? - should save to same folder What is the purpose of the line that ends with xlPasteFormats? don't know.  I'm a beginner and just copy this from somewhere.  Do you want to get rid of GetSaveAsFilename or does it suit your needs? - you can do anything.  it's not my original code.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, this will save your current workbook's name and add "hc" at the end

for example your workbook name = "book1.xlsx" then the output will be "book1 hc.xlsx"

```
Sub ExporthisBOM()

Dim fName As String

fName = Left(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5)



Sheets("Radiant_Trades").Copy

With ActiveSheet

    .UsedRange.Copy

    .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    '.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="" & fName & " hc " & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
```

xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub

Comment: Hi Thavisack VRCHDV, this solves my problem.  Although a strange quirk keeps saving everything to a specific folder, Temp/mp50.   I think this is an interior system quirk and I'm checking with my colleagues to see how to resolve it.  Thank you very much, this code is awesome.